# bash problems on pr2, robot command not found

Tags: ros, bashrc, bash, pr2, ros-groovy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey guys, I was having some issues with the kinect on the pr2 and so I had to uninstall and reinstall openni. I now get the kinect working (roslaunch / ros commands in general work), but somehow I think I messed up the bash configuration on the Pr2 machine. Now all commands robot start/stop, robot users etc, are not found.

I tried source again /opt/ros/groovy/setup.bash but nothing seems to work.

Also, right when I ssh into the pr2 machine AND when I type /bin/bash, I get the following:

-bash: /usr/bin/check-ssh-keys: No such file or directory
Sourcing /etc/ros/setup.bash
-bash: /etc/ros/setup.bash: No such file or directory

Do you guys know any workaround for this issue?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/193393/bash-problems-on-pr2,-robot-command-not-found/) by [Fred Eduardo](https://answers.ros.org/users/20246/fred-eduardo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 31 on 2014-09-24

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You didn't just mess up bash. It sounds like you uninstalled most of the system management utilities that are required on the PR2. Did the package manager ask you something like:

```
You are about to do something potentially harmful.
To continue type in the phrase 'Yes, do as I say!'
```

(You should never answer yes to that prompt without consulting a PR2 support representative first).

You should be able to get back to mostly working by reinstalling the pr2-core-groovy and pr2-network packages:

```
sudo apt-get install pr2-core-groovy pr2-network
```

You should probably follow that up by running a systemcheck to make sure things are functioning properly.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-09-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1